# What is the default location where mac stores sqlite3 databases

Tags: database, macos, path, sqlite, heroku

I want to pull data from a remote db into an sqlite database I just don't know where the path is to where mac stores sqlite3 files. It's just the default location.

---

This is the answer I came up with and will post it as an answer when SO lets me.

I don't know if this is the default but I never changed the sqlite3 settings on my macbook so I would assume that this is in fact the default location but like I said I don't know and it just worked for me.

The default location for me was

```
sqlite://my-apps-name.db
```

If you keep your sqlite db the same as your applications name all you need to do is give the application name which is also the db file's name after `sqlite://` and that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location for me was

```
sqlite://my-apps-name.db
```

If you keep your sqlite db the same as your applications name all you need to do is give the application name which is also the db file's name after sqlite:// and that should do it.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite3 is not a server-based DBMS like MySQL, which has a centralized location for all its served database files. It does not typically have a default (or even a central) location for databases. It relies on individual files for its databases, which could potentially be located anywhere within the file system.

If you want to create a database, it's up to you where to put it.