# Where can I find my sqlite3 database file in my mac?

Tags: database, xcode, file, sqlite

I created a sqlite3 database using terminal which has a static data. I need to add that db file into my xcode project to retrive data from it. But, I couldnt find the db file in my mac to add into my project. Where can I find my db file, so that I can add it into my Xcode. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My sqlite database is located here:
Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/skd version(i.e. 5.1)/Applications/a bunch of numbers and letters/Documents/yourdatabase

Comment: in x-code 6 it's Different Place !!!!.........exactly  at   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA/your app name.app/

Answer (score 2):

- ->Go to your Desktop(i.e click on the desktop)
- ->press (shift)+(cmd)+(G) a search tab should open up
- ->in the search tab enter this url "~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"
- -> find the latest device by the date modified and go further in the file explorer to /data/Containers/Data/Application/(APPLICATION_ID)/Documents/(databaseName).sqlite

Comment: where do I find the "APPLICATION_ID"?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the default directory path:

Open terminal.

Open your database trough the command line then type '.databases', the command outputs the path of your database file right next to 'main'.

In my case the command sequence was:

sqlite3 myDBFile.sqlite

sqlite3> .databases

Output:
0    main             /Users/Me/myDBFile.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at this thread, but I'm not sure that is what you want : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102133/what-is-the-default-location-where-mac-stores-sqlite3-databases)

Comment: I want to add the sqlite db file which I created in terminal to my project so that I can use it.