# What are the manual steps I need to take if I can't use the 'rails db:system:change --to=postgresql' command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not understanding what i need to do to update the database.yml.

1. Do I have to do anything inside a postgresql console?
2. What do I need to update in my database.yml?

I have been running my development app with sqlite3 up until this point.

Using Rails 5.0.7.2, which came default on my machine at the time.

I have a feeling it has to do with this build error:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Psych::BadAlias: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
       Unknown alias: default
       /tmp/build_6f080167/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:137:in `database_configuration'
```

Update:

this is what I previously had:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

When I try to go to:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default #<--- psych error should be fixed using &default
  adapter: postgresql #<--- from sqlite
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.psql

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.psql

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.psql
```

I get an error:

> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist

Do I need username and password??
Idk what im doing

Comment: This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114479/1880203) outlines how to bring your `database.yml` file into compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to get any data from your current databases:

1. Switch from the `sqlite3` gem to the `pg` gem in your `Gemfile`.

Uninstall the sqlite3 gem if you want: `gem uninstall sqlite3`

Install the `pg` gem: `gem install pg` (or `bundle install` after adding the gem to your gemfile)

2. Update your `database.yml` file:

```yaml
default: &default #<--- psych error should be fixed using &default
  adapter: postgresql #<--- from sqlite
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

... # each database specific settings
```

3. Create your database:

`rails db:create`

If this doesn't work, it'll tell you which migration failed and you can see what table or column data was sqlite specific (but it'd be a rare case)

4. Remove old sqlite database files on your machine

Database file locations really depend on how you installed sqlite, but check `/usr/bin` and be careful to only delete the test and development databases for this app (Mac uses SQlite for some things, so don't delete those files by accident). [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9902330/1880203) has other locations where your SQlite databases could be located.

Comment: i enter postgresql and then create a user called test, but i still get the following error: _PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"_

Comment: could you include an example on the database specific settings? My original database.yml was very simple for sqlite3, but im strugging with converting to postgresql database.yml

Comment: I updated my question, is it not as simple as keeping my .yml the same besides editing the default: like you gave me?

Comment: See [the configuration guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: Follow steps 1 and 2 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-macos) to ensure you have Postgres setup properly.